# Wildfly Server local server debug panel shows error "http connector is not enabled for server profile"

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss7.x

I setup a local **JBoss/Wildfly** server launch configuraiton in Intellij Idea. When I attempt to start the server, the configuration panel pops up and shows following error.

> Error: HTTP connector is not enabled for server profile

[image: Picture of Idea Launch Console wit Error]

I could not find anything in the Idea help what this means and how to fix it. The server is a keycloak distro but is just plain wildfly 10 with an extra subsystem.

Has anyone seen this before and knows how to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce this with fresh installation of keycloak 3.2.1 [from here](http://www.keycloak.org/archive/downloads-3.2.1.html)

IDEA looks for the 2 following xpath's searching for a HTTP connector settings:

```
"/ns:server/ns:profile/*[local-name()='subsystem']/*[local-name()='server']/*[local-name()='http-listener'][@*[local-name()='socket-binding' and .='http']]",
"/ns:server/ns:profile/*[local-name()='subsystem']/*[local-name()='connector'][@*[local-name()='socket-binding' and .='http']]"};
```

For me playing with the fresh keycloak distribution the first xpath hits at the following markup:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
```

Please check your configuration around this place. 
If this does not help, please attach your standalone.xml or at least the relevant part of it.

Comment: Hmm inspecting the standalone.xml file I can see that the entire profile node ( `/ns:server/ns:profile` ) has gone missing. Not sure if that was operator error but using a freshly untar'ed home removes the error. Thanks @michael-golubev for the pointer and taking time to have a look.

Answer (score 2):

In my case changing of 'JRE' from 'Default' to explicit one (Even though it was the same as it was in parentheses in the default version) solved the problem.